# How to mask padded 0s in pytorch for RNN model training?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I have some time series data padded with 0s in the shape of (Batch, length, features). For more detail, I extracted MFCCs from audio files with (60,40), 60 frames, and 40 MFCCs for each audio file input.

I used to run Tensorflow and applied the `Masking` layer with the value I wish to mask.

I am trying to do the same thing in Pytorch. I have done some research on this and found people mentioning `pack_padded_sequence`  from `from torch.nn.utils.rnn`

However, it appears that I have to prepare a list that contains the length of valid indexes for each input.

Even if I create a list of the length of the valid indexes, can it deal with the random state in `train_test_split`?

---

updated on 2022 July 27

It appears that `pack_padded_sequence` is the only way to do a mask for Pytorch RNN.
I have rewritten the dataset preparation codes and created a list containing all the 2D array data. It is a list with a length of 12746 and the 2d array inside is in the form of (x,40); "x" can be any number lower than 60. So basically I am going to prepare data for training in the shape of (12746,60,40)

How should I proceed as the packed sequence cannot be created as a PyTorch dataset?

```
class mydata(Dataset):
   def __init__(self, X, y):
        self.X = torch.FloatTensor(X)
        self.y = torch.FloatTensor(y)
                
   def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)
    
   def __getitem__(self, index):
        y = self.y[index]
        X = self.X[index] 
        return X,y


padded = pad_sequence(data, batch_first=True, padding_value=0.0)
lengths = torch.tensor([len(t) for t in data])
# print('#padded', padded)

print('--------------------------------------------')
packed = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(padded, lengths.to('cpu'), batch_first=True, enforce_sorted=False)

#split them into 0.7 proportion. It was done using Train_test_split.
X_train = packed[0:8900]
y_train = y[:8900]
X_valid = packed[8900:]
y_valid = y[8900:]

train_dataset = mytools.mydata(X_train,y_train)
valid_dataset = mytools.mydata(X_valid,y_valid)
trainloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=256, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
validloader = DataLoader(valid_dataset, batch_size=256, shuffle=False, num_workers=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence`. Here is an example:
`batch_first` is False by default. Here is for `batch_first=False`:

```
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence

a = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
b = torch.tensor([0, 1])
c = torch.tensor([0, 5, 6, 8])

padded = pad_sequence([a, b, c], padding_value=0.0)
print('#padded', padded)

lengths = torch.tensor([len(t) for t in [a, b, c]])
packed = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(padded, lengths.to('cpu'), enforce_sorted=False)
print('#packed', packed)

output, lengths = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(packed)
print('output', output, '\n lengths', lengths )
```

Output:

```
#padded tensor([[1, 0, 0],
        [2, 1, 5],
        [3, 0, 6],
        [0, 0, 8]])
#packed PackedSequence(data=tensor([0, 1, 0, 5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 8]), batch_sizes=tensor([3, 3, 2, 1]), sorted_indices=tensor([2, 0, 1]), unsorted_indices=tensor([1, 2, 0]))
output tensor([[1, 0, 0],
        [2, 1, 5],
        [3, 0, 6],
        [0, 0, 8]]) 
 lengths tensor([3, 2, 4])
```

and here is for `batch_first=True`:

```
padded = pad_sequence([a, b, c], batch_first=True, padding_value=0.0)
print('#padded', padded)

lengths = torch.tensor([len(t) for t in [a, b, c]])
packed = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(padded, lengths.to('cpu'), batch_first=True, enforce_sorted=False)
print('#packed', packed)

output, lengths = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(packed, batch_first=True)
print('output', output, '\n lengths', lengths )
```

Output:

```
#padded tensor([[1, 2, 3, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 5, 6, 8]])
#packed PackedSequence(data=tensor([0, 1, 0, 5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 8]), batch_sizes=tensor([3, 3, 2, 1]), sorted_indices=tensor([2, 0, 1]), unsorted_indices=tensor([1, 2, 0]))
output tensor([[1, 2, 3, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 5, 6, 8]]) 
 lengths tensor([3, 2, 4])
```

Then you can work with packed values such as `packed_output, (hidden, cell) = your_lstm(packed)`. You can use `hidden` as usual but the `packed_output` will be packed but you can convert it to batched case using `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence`. **Remember** that if you set `batch_first=False` you should also do it in your `LSTM`.

If you have problem with splitting, you can do it manually as follows:

```
seq = [a, b, c]
lengths = [len(t) for t in seq]

import random
idx = np.arange(len(seq))
random.shuffle(idx)

seq_shuffled = [seq[i] for i in idx]
lengths _shuffled = [lengths [i] for i in idx]
```

Comment: You are actually doing the padding, but i have done it during my data preparation step. What I wishto know is how to let the model knows that 0s are not for training.

Comment: Would you mind rewriting the codes for `batch_first=True` because i copied and run for batch first and got an error?  In addition, even i prepare the `lengths` list but this will lead to a problem when I have a different `random_state`, the `lengths` cannot be shifted together with the `train_test_split` function.

Comment: I edited the solution and added `batch_first=True`.

Comment: Hi bpfrd, I have worked as you suggested but more questions came up. How should I prepare the torch.dataset. Should I prepare the dataset first and then run the `pack_padded_sequence` right before feeding it into the model? I have updated my question